# JEST MOCK - How can I mock a function after test all a route

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

**I need to mock the process function who is in the GatewayImpl class to resolve me the 'mockData' payload, but before do that I need to test all the route.**

```
import payload from './payloads/payloadRequire';        // payload to send
import {GatewayImpl} from '../src/classes/GatewayImpl'; //class where the function is 
import mockData from './mockData/mockData';            // payload to response

  var fClass = new GatewayImpl;
    request.post('/route/test').send(payload) // route I need to test and the payload
//const procc = fClass.proccess -> the function on GatewayImpl class calls process
    const spy = jest
    .spyOn(GatewayImpl, 'procc' ) //I don't know how to spy this class and function
    .mockReturnValue(mockData) // Need to resolve the Mockdata.json when the function process be called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `__mocks__` directory to `src/classes`.
2. Add `GatewayImpl.js` to `__mocks__`.
3. In `__mocks__/GatewayImpl.js`

```js
// I don't know how GatewayImpl is implemented.
exports.GatewayImpl = {
  procc = jest.fn();
}
```

4. In the test file, insert `jest.mock('../src/classes/GatewayImpl')` to top.

```js
jest.mock('../src/classes/GatewayImpl')
import payload from './payloads/payloadRequire';        // payload to send
import {GatewayImpl} from '../src/classes/GatewayImpl'; //class where the function is 
import mockData from './mockData/mockData';            // payload to response
```

5. Inside of `beforeAll` or `beforeEach`, `GatewayImpl.procc.mockReturnValue(mockData)` to mock return value.

```js
describe('procc', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    GatewayImpl.procc.mockReturnValue(mockData);
  });
  it('returns a data', () => {
    request.post('/route/test').send(payload);
    expect(GatewayImpl.procc()).toBe(mockData);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does the "_mocks_" directory have to be in the same folder as the class I'm mocking?